# Symfony 5 keep to seeing postgre database when i set mysql on docker and in the all config files

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony

I'm new in Symfony 5.4/Docker, and i'm trying to understand how can i connect to docker mysql database.

I'm start a project where i will use a DB running on remote machine with Docker (mysql). So, i ve configured this DB and i have import all data inside correctly. So i started to create repository and entity to push into my DB.

The problem is symfony continue to see PostgreSql DB when i set Mysql in every configuration. But i have two strange things.

1. When i try to push into the database some entities, i got this error
   [image]
2. If i exec `symfony var:export`, i can see some error in the environment variables:
   [image]

He's continuing to see Postgre as Database.

How is possible?
**.env file**

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=84cac6cb4e921f9349604ecf6784d220
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> symfony/webapp-pack ###
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default?auto_setup=0
###< symfony/webapp-pack ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/d2b48de2d4398d46a2faa17526b8e3d2a0f1d9110dc06cc2c53f54127dfeec37?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"

# database credentials
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=example # this is the secret password

###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/messenger ###
# Choose one of the transports below
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f/messages
# MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=redis://localhost:6379/messages
###< symfony/messenger ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
# MAILER_DSN=null://null
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> blackfireio/blackfire-symfony-meta ###
# Get your SERVER credentials at https://blackfire.io/my/settings/credentials
# BLACKFIRE_SERVER_ID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
# BLACKFIRE_SERVER_TOKEN=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
###< blackfireio/blackfire-symfony-meta ###
```

**doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        server_version: '8.0'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
    version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: mysql:8
    command: mysqld  
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password


  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: Do you have another `.env*` files that could overwrite your conf? `127.0.0.1:3306` should probably be `database` (the name of the database container) and `serverVersion=5.7` should be `serverVersion=8.0` to match with your database.

Comment: no, i don't have an other env file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever had postgres in and around this project? Because I had a similar issue, but mine was because I had a Postgres container active on my machine, I had to stop it before Symfony would use my MySQL connection. For the record I've no idea why it's doing this behaviour.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35493017)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).